# Formatting a JSON Response to build a URL

Tags: javascript, json, django

I'm *incredibly* stuck on trying to format receive a JSON response, and format it. Order of operations:

1. Query a REST API endpoint ([https://endpoint.com/api/v1/employee?id={username}](https://endpoint.com/api/v1/employee?id=%7Busername%7D))
2. Receive JSON response: `{"employee":{"full name":"Example Name","function":"Role","office":"Office Location",team":"Team 1|Team 2|Team 3|"}}`

In my base.js file within my django app, I am hoping to extract the team strings and pass them into another URL. What way can I do this? When I `$.getJSON` from the endpoint I receive responseJSON, responseText, etc. but I'm unable to pull them out/use them in any way.

Comment: What format do you need for the team values in the new url? Also show us how you are using `$.getJSON` since it doesn't sound like you are using it correctly either

Comment: I used the .getJSON on the URL above in step 1. And the format would need to be a string that I could pass into a new URL.

Comment: Yes but you shouldn't need to do anything with responseText, or responseJSON properties if you are using it correctly. So lets start with using it properly as well as how you need to structure the new url with the team values

Comment: ```let url = https://endpoint.com/api/v1/employee?id={username}
let response = $.getJSON(url)```

and the new url would look like: 
https://otherurl.com/endpoint/endpoint?teams=teams%separated%7Clike%20so

Comment: Ok...that's not how it works   try `$.getJSON(url).then(data => console.log(data))`. Ajax methods are asynchronous

Comment: Put that url format in question inside code block so it is easy to read as code not as a link

Comment: ```https://otherurl.com/endpoint/endpoint?teams=teams%separated%7Clike%20so``` 

So now that .getJSON is fixed, it returns the JSON object with `teams` as a result, but I am wondering how to pull that out and pass it into another string

Comment: `data.employee.team` will give you the string

Comment: Thanks! That seems to be working conceptually. Unfortunately, the `employee` portion is dynamic from the JSON api response, and so data.employee.team doesn't work. Do you know of a workaround to this?

Comment: Show more samples

Answer (score 0):

In order to fetch and parse json I would suggest you to use the following `fetch` structure:

```
fetch('https://endpoint.com/api/v1/employee?id=username')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
    let teams = data.team.split('|');
    // Do something with team names
  });
```

Let's break down what this does per line:

1. First we use `fetch` to request data from the defined url
2. Then we convert the response to a json object
3. Finally we retrieve the string with team values using the `data.teams` statement, after which we immediately convert the list of team names to an array by using `split` and the defined delimiter `|`.

After this you should be able to do whatever you'd like with the team names. You could use them to make another API call as well. If you're interested, be sure to checkout the `fetch` [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch), as well as the `split` [documentation](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/es6/es6_string_split.htm) if you are not yet familiar with that function.

The solution above assumes that the response will be a 200, for error handling you should check out the `fetch` documentation above.